# Image type validation is not working in yii

Tags: image

In my model, the validation code for image type is:

```
array('employeedetails_photo', 'file', 'types' => 'jpg, gif, png,jpeg', 'message' => 'Please upload only images in the format jpg, gif, png'),
```

But, if I'm uploading a JPEG image also shown the error message.